# Problem with rosjava installation

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Iam new to ROS trying to install rosjava in ubuntu 11.10 fuerte.But when Iam Trying to execute the following command:
rosws merge h**ps://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/.rosinstall

Iam getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/rosws", line 65, in 
sys.exit(rosinstall.rosws_cli.rosws_main(sys.argv))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall/rosws_cli.py", line 441, in rosws_main
os.getcwd(),
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

How can I install rosjava successfully without these errors?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63403/problem-with-rosjava-installation/) by [Jhansi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4964/jhansi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your problem doesn't seem to be related to rosjava, but to rosinstall/rosws. On Ubuntu, you should remove the old rosinstall stuff installed via pip and instead use the deb version:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall*
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vcstools*
```

then

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall
```

Also, the .rosinstall link in the rosjava doc is out of date. After running the steps above, you should do this:

```
mkdir ~/my_workspace
cd ~/my_workspace
rosws init
rosws merge /opt/ros/groovy/.rosinstall
rosws set --git --version=groovy-devel rosjava_core 'git://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core.git'
rosws update
source setup.bash
```

I've submitted pull requests [161](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/pull/161) and [162](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/pull/162) to fix the rosjava documentation.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jhansi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4964/jhansi/) on 2013-05-27**:
rosws update gives error as:[rosjava_core] Updating /home/jhansi/my_workspace/rosjava_core
WARNING [vcstools] Command failed: 'git fetch'
run at: '/home/jhansi/my_workspace/rosjava_core'
errcode: 128:
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-05-28**:
Can you post the relevant lines of your .rosinstall file, i.e. the output of `grep -A 1 rosjava_core $ROS_WORKSPACE/.rosinstall`?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-05-30**:
Which error are you getting? The "No such file"? In that case, I guess it's not rosjava specific, and I'd ask a new question like "rosinstall fails on OSX". Or do you get the "remote hung up" one? Even after following all steps above with a fresh work space?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-05-31**:
So you don't get any error during the rosinstall? In that case, it's a different problem and doesn't belong into this question, sorry.